# Is it possible to get the placeCategory id of a place? (iOS Here SDK Explore Edition)

Tags: here-api

I want to use the category id of the place described here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-places/places-category-system-full.html.

How can i get it? Via the searchEngine?

I tried:

```
        if !places.isEmpty {
            for place in places {
                let placeIdQuery = PlaceIdQuery(place.id)
                searchEngine.search(placeIdQuery: placeIdQuery, languageCode: .deDe, completion: onFollowUpSearchCompleted)
            }
        }
```

But i only get the same places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
Every Place has the optional details -> category.